# Cannot reach for properties or methods

Tags: javascript

I have difficulties understanding why my variable is undefined.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>webPage</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="JS/const.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/event.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Player.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Map.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/App.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

So i assume that the browser reads the Player file first, then the Map file and the the App file(correct me if i'm wrong).

**App.js**

```
var app;

var App = function (){
    this.map = new Map();
    this.player = new Player();
};


(function (){
    app = new App();
})();
```

But when i want to reach for a property or a method of the Map class for exemple `app.map.msg`, firebug throws a typeError and says that app is not defined... Plus, typeError means that the variable does exist but that the operation you're trying to perform is not appropriate for the value it contains.

So it means my browser acknowledges my variable but not my App class??

I'm really confused so any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: When are you trying to access app.map.msg ? I don't see it in your code

Comment: Actually i try to access app.map.msg in Map.js...

Comment: That will not work because you are declaring app after loading Map.js, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you defined map correctly.

here is a working example tested on fiddle.

```
var app;
function Map() {
    this.msg = " hey, i am map" ;
}

function Player () {
    this.msg = " hey, i am player" ;
}

var App = function (){
   this.map = new Map();
   this.player = new Player();
};


(function (){
    app = new App();
    document.getElementById ( 'output' ) .innerHTML = app.map.msg
 })();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bdsduv08/